# BootstrapVue b-form-checkbox&radio vertical center in Vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuetify.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Vuetify as our primary framework and added some of Bootstrap-Vue components like b-form-checkbox&radio.

I'm trying to figure it out how to vertical center my bootstrap-vue checkbox and text.
so far, I've tried::

1. vertical-align="baseline"
2. align="center"
3. justify="center" // I know it's for horizontal but... I've tried anyway
4. class="align-middle"

My framework structure is

```
    <v-container>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <b-form-checkbox>
                ABCD
              </b-form-checkbox>
   ....
    </v-container>
```

I've tried adding them into v-col, v-row and b-form-checkbox, and wrapped checkbox with span and added into span too but none of them worked.

Please help!

Comment: is "ABCD" the element you want to vertically center?

Comment: checkbox and "ABCD". checkbox itself is somehow align="bottom" and abcd is somehow align="top" which is very weird cuz I didn't set any align at all... they are default

Comment: Right, so I would add a `<div>` to surround the `<b-form-checkbox>` and use that `div` as the container.  Then set the style on the `<b-form-checkbox>` according to the content as I described in my answer.

Comment: Could you maybe include a screen shot of your current result?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-roentgen-hb2i5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The trick is that you have to set the `position` to `relative` on whatever element contains the components you want to center vertically.  Then on the components you center vertically, you essentially say, "Put the top of this component half-way down its parent, then move it up by half of its height"

You can see that in the `vertCenterContentContainer` class and the `vertCenteredContent` class in the vue component style.

The salient portions are:

```
.vertCenterContentContainer{
  ...
  position: relative;
}

.vertCenteredContent{
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: well... it doesn't work.. it change the position not align... I've tried exactly what you wrote here, but align is still the same... but Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure all containers are 100% the height of their parents?

Comment: Yes! So sorry for late reply. I've checked Bootstrap forum and fount out it's ongoing issue to Bootstrap V4. They will fix it next year(2020) with version 5.  https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/3745